# исключить папку из индекса git

Tags: git, gitignore

Не работает правило, по исключению папки в файле *.gitignore* , который лежит в папке с проектом.

**правило:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**git всё равно не игнорирует папку .idea:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `.idea` это файл, папка `/.idea/`

Comment: @stas0k сделай так: /.idea

Comment: пробовал и так и по всякому. хорошо ниже подсказали удалить из индекса, git rm -r --cached .idea

Comment: @stackanon по строке `.idea` отлично игнорируются и файлы и папки с таким именем. Проверьте )

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Вы делаете всё правильно и это исключит папку `.idea` из потенциального добавления untracked файлов. Ваша проблема в том, что `.idea` уже в репозитории. Нужно сначала её оттуда исключить, а потом она заново туда не будет пытаться проникнуть.
Попробуйте сделать:

```
git rm -r --cached .idea
```