# Можно ли скрыть файлы .idea/gradle.xml и .idea/misc.xml из отслеживаемых?

Tags: git, gitignore

Я добавил эти файлы в `.gitignore` вот так

```
# Gradle:
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/libraries

.idea/misc.xml
```

но все равно как только я открываю проект и проверяю команду `git status` она мне показывает вот такое

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom$ git status 
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   .idea/gradle.xml
modified:   .idea/misc.xml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Что сделал не так? Почему эти файлы постоянно попадают в отслеживаемые?

Comment: Ну, и [вчерашний](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573888/исключить-папку-из-индекса-git/573902#573902) ответ на фактически тот же вопрос.