# Как игнорировать папки?

Tags: git

node-modules(и другие) в git ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [исключить папку из индекса git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573888/%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0-git)

Comment: NO. I know that I need to create a .gitignore folder, but I don’t know what to do next. Your answer does not solve my problem, there is a completely different problem.

Comment: В справке все доходчиво написано, даже с примерами. И здесь говорят по-русски.

Comment: Вы комментировали(даже если это copy paste) на английском, и поэтому я ответила на таком же языке. Я знаю что этот сайт русскоязычный. Вы просто наверху другую ссылку отметили(там совсем друга проблема была). Спасибо, я проанализирую справку.

Comment: Это не я, это глюк системы - служебные сообщения в последнее время на английском.

Comment: Сорри тогда, не знала )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Не игнорируются файлы в .gitignore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432432/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-gitignore)

Answer (score 1):

gitignore - Определяет намеренно не отслеживаемые файлы для игнорирования